# New Instalation of Ubuntu 13.4

Tags: mount

hi guys i Installed new Ubuntu yesterday today when i switched on my pc i got this message

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/mperequest/26E00037E000102B: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/mperequest/26E00037E000102B"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Please Assist

Comment: Are you on a dual boot or single boot? Have you followed the suggestion in the error? I guess its an dual boot with Windows 8.

Comment: is dual boot. Sorry i actually get this error message when i click windows partition and i shutdown windows fully.

Comment: Try to [disable/off the hibernation](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/783-elevated-command-prompt.html) through power option then shutdown windows completely and restart again to boot in to ubuntu directly.

Comment: Well come, if everything is working plz accept the answer below as your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do "quick start" Windows 8 saves driver settings in the hiberfil.sys file - the same file traditionally used by Windows to save a memory snapshot when you hibernate. That's why the mount command is complaining.

You have to disable hibernation in order to mount the partition successfully.

Try this link: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/783-elevated-command-prompt.html